# I can't take the value of Markdown with Jquery Serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, markdown

In my project im using this MarkDown .
https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor

To take the values of a form im using the Jquery Serialize , the problem is that it doesn't work with the MarkDown, with a simple Textarea my code works.

The problem is with this ( Here there is the Markdown ).

```
<textarea id="messaggio" name="testo"></textarea>
```

**Script to load the markdown**

```
<script>
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: $("#messaggio")[0] });
</script>
```

**JQUERY SERIALIZE**

```
$("#invio").click(function(){

    var dati = $("#form").serialize(); //recupera tutti i valori del form automaticamente

    //form invio dati post ajax

    alert(dati);

    //invio
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/includes/inserisci.php",
    data: dati,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg)
    {
    alert("Chiamata inviata con successo");

    },
    error: function()
    {
    alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...");
    }

    });//ajax

    });//bottone click
```

**Inserisci.php**

```
<?php
include('../core.php');
$titolo= urldecode($_POST['titolo']); 
$post= urldecode($_POST['testo']);


$sql = mysql_query("")or die("Non riuscito");

mysql_close();

?>
```

**FORM**

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal shadow-z-1" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: 8px;">Inserisci un Post</legend>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Titolo</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputText" name="titolo" placeholder="Scrivi qui il Titolo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label" >Messaggio</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea id="messaggio" name="testo"></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>

           <div class="form-group is-empty is-fileinput">
                <label for="inputFile" class="col-md-2 control-label">File</label>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse..." pmbx_context="19E61A0C-3526-4E51-8535-935982C4C335">
                  <input type="file" id="inputFile" multiple="" pmbx_context="1D2BCAEA-08CC-476A-8F4A-EF6BD51B9102">
                </div>
              <span class="material-input"></span></div>

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('modalposta').style.display = 'none';">Cancel</button>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="invio" onClick="nascondiform();return false;">Submit</button>
                  <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick='send(); return false;' >Submit</button>-->
                </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please look at the documentation: https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor you need  `var dati = simplemde.value()`

Comment: I know. But how implement this with jquery serialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work in this way.

```
var dati = $("#form").serialize()+"&text="+simplemde.value();
```

**php**

```
$post= urldecode($_POST['text']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the documentation: github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor you need

```
simplemde.value()
```

Serialise is for the form only. You can try to copy the value back to the textarea before serialising:

```
 $("#messagio").val(simplemde.value());
 var dati = $("#form").serialize(); //recupera tutti i valori del form automaticamente
```

or

```
var dati = $("#form").serialize()+"&text="+JSON.stringify(simplemde.value());
```

possibly

```
var dati = $("#form").serialize()+"&text="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(simplemde.value()));
```

Comment: For this if i put the value in <textarea id="messaggio" name="testo"></textarea> , $("#messaggio").val(simplemde.value()); for you work? Or i need of a other textarea?

Comment: $("#messagio").val(simplemde.value());
var dati = $("#form").serialize() dont work.

Comment: Can you right-click on the form and inspect element to see what it looks like? Also if there are errors in the console?

Comment: With var dati = $("#form").serialize()+"&text="+JSON.stringify(simplemde.value()); give me this https://i.gyazo.com/79c37080780c775ec8acf6a1807501ad.png.

Comment: No, the value is null in my Database. See the file in php.

Comment: Can you just echo what is sent to the server?

Comment: var dati = $("#form").serialize()+"&testo="+JSON.stringify(simplemde.value());  NO TEXT but TESTO . Now the problem is that adds " at the beginning and end of message . Example Hello -> "Hello"

Comment: I have no more suggestions